# Copying text into corresponding file of corresponding folder

Tags: bash, unix, sed

In a given directory, I have 9 folders, each one labelled by its number, as well as a folder called "files", such that:

```
ls 
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 files
```

Each folder from 1-9 contains another set of folder 1-7:

```
cd 1/
ls 
1 2 3 4 5 6 7
```

And each folder in 1-7 has an input file, the name of which depends on the directory, such that (for example) the input file of folder 3 in folder 8 is called "8-3.inp", and input file of folder 2 in folder 1 would be "1-2.inp"

In the "files" folder, I also have 9 folders similarly labeled 1-9. In each of these 9 folder, I have 7 text files, such that any one of these 9 folders would contain:

```
1.txt 2.txt 3.txt 4.txt 5.txt 6.txt 7.txt
```

I want to paste all the contents of the txt files into the 26th line of the corresponding input folders. For example, I would want all the text contents of /files/8/2.inp to be copied into the 26th line of /8/2/8-2.inp

Is there a way to do this? I think it can be done with the sed command, but how to correlate all the indices of the files to copy in the right place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure I have fully understood your problem. But here is a simple bash script that should do the job. It uses the `sed` ability to apply actions on an address range.

```
tmpfile=tmpfile
for i in $(seq 1 9)
do
  for j in $(seq 1 7)
  do
    ifile2=$i/$j/$i-$j.inp
    # ofile is identical to ifile2. Give ofile it a different extension for testing
    ofile=$i/$j/$i-$j.inp
    ifile=files/$i/$j.inp
    # copy lines 1-25 to tempfile
    # -n option suppresses normal sed output, 
    #     on selected range (1,25) print lines (p)
    sed -n '1,25p' <$ifile2 > $tmpfile;
    # append input file to tempfile
    cat $ifile >> $tmpfile
    # append files 27-end to tempfile.
    # just ask sed to delete lines 1-26 and to print others (default sed behavior)
    # note line 26 is suppressed
    sed '1,26d' <$ifile2 >> $tmpfile
    # move tempfile to result file
    mv $tmpfile $ofile
  done
done
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed & parallel):

```
parallel sed -i -e \'26rfiles/{1}/{2}.txt\' -e \'26d\' {1}/{2} ::: {1..9} ::: {1..7}
```

Use parallel to simplify loops and sed to replace the 26th line of each file by the contents of its namesake in the files directory.